# How to debug an Android Service

Tags: android

I have created a class that descends from android.app.Service.

I am then calling it from one of my activities using

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), SavedArticlesService.class);
getActivity().startService(i);
```

Everything runs ok, no errors returned, but the work within the service is not getting completed (downloading a file).  I have tried setting breakpoints within the service but they never are reached.  I have also tried to use Log to see messages in LogCat, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: I think you should use getApplicationContext() or this instead of getActivity()

Comment: Is the service start and the job is not completed? Or event the `onCreate()` is not called? (because you said about LogCat "nothing is displayed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the issue was that I had included it in the AndroidManifest.xml file incorrectly.  My service is in a services subpackage so it was necessary

`<service
   android:name=".services.MyService"
   android:label="My Service" >
</service>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps export the service?
If you export the service, it is run on a different process and the breakpoints won't work.

Try setting `exported="false"` in your android manifest on the service and then try again.

You can set it back to exported once you're done debugging.

Logcat messages should still work though, but might show up under a different process as well. Try looking in "All messages".